# Trying to get multiple colors per vertex of triangle

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

This is my JavaScript Code:

```
// TranslatedTriangle.js (c) 2012 matsuda
// Vertex shader program
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'attribute vec3 a_Color;\n' +
  'varying vec3 v_Color;\n' +
  'uniform vec4 u_Translation;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  a_Color = v_Color;\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position + u_Translation;\n' +
  '}\n';

// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  'precision mediump float;\n' +
  'varying vec3 v_Color;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = vec4(v_Color, 1.0);\n' +
  '}\n';

// The translation distance for x, y, and z direction
var Tx = 0.5, Ty = 0.5, Tz = 0.0;

function main() {
//  // Retrieve <canvas> element
  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

//  // Get the rendering context for WebGL
  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
    return;
  }

//  // Initialize shaders
  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
    console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
    return;
  }

  // Write the positions of vertices to a vertex shader
  var n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
  if (n < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
    return;
  }

  // Pass the translation distance to the vertex shader
  var u_Translation = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_Translation');
  if (!u_Translation) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_Translation');
    return;
  }
  gl.uniform4f(u_Translation, Tx, Ty, Tz, 0.0);

//  // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

//  // Clear <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Draw the rectangle
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, n);
}

function initVertexBuffers(gl) {

//  // Triangle Verticies
  var vertices = new Float32Array(
  [ // x, y             r, g, b
    0.0, 0.5,           1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5,         0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
    0.5, -0.5,          0.0, 0.0, 1.0
  ]);

  var n = 3; // The number of vertices

//  // Create a buffer object
  var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  if (!vertexBuffer) {
    console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
    return -1;
  }
  // Bind the buffer object to target
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
  // Write date into the buffer object
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

//  // Assign the buffer object to the attribute variable
  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }
  // Assign the buffer object to the attribute variable
  var a_Color = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Color');
  if (a_Color < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);

  // Enable the assignment to a_Position variable
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Color);
  return n;
}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. I am getting a "Failed to compile shader: ERROR: 0:6: 'assign' : 1-value required (can't modify an attribute "a_Color")

Anyone have any insight on what my problem could be? I used this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB0ZVUrI4Aw as a guide. I am trying to understand how to get multiple colors per vertex, but once I figure that out I need to make 4 triangles, which all have different colors.

Comment: Please read the error message: ERROR: 0:6: 'assign' : 1-value required (**can't modify an attribute "a_Color"**). You do the assignment in the wrong direction. It has to be `v_Color = a_Color;` instead of `a_Color = v_Color;`

Comment: Sorry I am still prone to stupid mix-ups. I was struggling with this for an hour. Thank you so much for your help.